# Adding a field to a database / overriding default options from dropdown that are present

Tags: php, html, sql

This is for a file upload script that I'm trying to improve.  I simply can't settle on one method and have run into various problems.

When a file is uploaded it is given an access category, this is to determine who can see the file at a later date.  I was using an enum for this field but now it is a simple varchar.

The list of options is displayed in a dropdown box on the form by using a select distinct statement.

```
 <div class="uploadFormE">
                <label>Access Category: </label>
                <select name="accessCategory[]">
                    <?php
                        foreach($accessCategories as $eachCat){
                            $val = $eachCat['accessCategory'];
                           echo "<option value=" .$val.">" .$val. "</option>";
                        }

                    ?>
                </select>
            </div>

            OR TYPE NEW ONE

            <div class="uploadFormE">
                <label>New Access Category: </label>
                <input type="text" name="accessCategory[]"> </input>
            </div>
```

the problem is the "Or type a new one" part. (the default setting from the dropdown is overriding what may be typed into the input field)

I'd like to give the uploader an opportunity for adding a new category.

Is there a workaround?  If there is a cleaner better way then I'm all ears.  I was going to use a separate function to "add a category" but as it's a field that's not possible.  There are also not enough values to justify a new table and I couldn't make enums work on update.

Thanks.

EDIT:

```
<div class="uploadFormE">
                <label>Access Category: </label>
                <select name="accessCategory[]">
                    <?php
                        foreach($accessCategories as $eachCat){
                            $val = $eachCat['accessCategory'];
                           echo "<option value=" .$val.">" .$val. "</option>";
                        }
                    ?>
                    <option value="newCat">New Category?</option>
                </select>
            </div>


            <div class="uploadFormE">
                <label>New Access Category: </label>
                <input type="text" class="GAH" name="newCategory"> </input>
            </div>


           $comments = htmlentities( trim( $_POST['comments'][$i] ) );

            if($_POST['accessCategory[]'] == "newCat"){
                $accessCat = htmlentities( trim ($_POST['newCategory'][$i]));
            }else{
                $accessCat = htmlentities( trim ($_POST['accessCategory'][$i]));
            }

            //doc, pdf, etc etc
            $category = htmlentities( trim( $_POST['category'][$i] ) );

            if($file['name'] != ""){
                $training->uploadDocument( $fileName, $category, $comments, $accessCat );
            }
```

Comment: can't you just give the text input a separate name, add another option in the select giving it a value of -1 or "" and work with if statements on the posted names?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem space correctly you have two elements with the same name. Don't.
Instead create unique id and name and have an if statement in your php to handle.

If you can't - create a third, hidden, element and do some javascript to copy values into it and use this third element's value in your PHP.

Comment: I see what you mean but navigating the issue of one being set instead of the other is still a problem for me.  IF I label them 1 and 2 for example.  I can use a If(islet(a)){accessLvl = a etc but the dropdown has a default option which still overrides.

Comment: Suggestion: Have a "nothing selected" option in the dropdown. When the user edits something in the textbox; set the dropdown to this "nothing selected". If the users selects something from the dropdown; clear the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a new option is fairly easy.  I would do this by (untested code stub):

```
$output="<div class='uploadFormE'><label>Access Category: </label><select name="accessCategory" onChange=\"myjs(this.value)\">";
foreach($accessCategories as $eachCat)
    {
        $val = $eachCat['accessCategory'];
        $output.="<option value='$val'>$val</option>";
    }
$output.="<OPTION value='0' selected='yes'>Add New</OPTION></SELECT>";

$output.="<SPAN id='addnewspan' style='display: none;'><INPUT type='text' name='mynewdata'></SPAN>";

$output.="</DIV>";
echo $output;
```

The JS:

```
function myjs(theval)
    {
    if(theval=="0")
        {
        document.getElementById("addnewspan").style.display="block;";
        }
        else
        {
        document.getElementById("addnewspan").style.display="none;";
        }
    }
```

You will need to deal with the input of course in another file.

EDIT:

In order to handle the input you just test your $_POST variable.

```
if($_POST['accessCategory']=='0')
    {
    $category=$_POST['mynewdata'];
    }
    else
    {
    $category=$_POST['accessCategory'];
    }
    //do something with $category.
```

NB:  I'd be VERY careful with any user additions to access - this has to be a very closely held feature of your application.

A few things to note:

1. Try not to mix php and html as in your example - it makes it very hard to follow and to debug.
2. "STUFF".$stuff."STUFF" is equivalent to "STUFF$stuffSTUFF".
3. use single quotes if you are going to concatenate as it reduces load on the parser.

Don't be afraid to use tables with only a few values.  Overall it is much better to store an integer reference to these small lists than to store the values repeatedly.  It also makes debugging and updates easier.

If you need help designing the priveleges tables, please just ask.

Comment: Hi Robert, thanks for the tips and pointers.  The layout of the form is not a problem, I'm happy for the text box to always be visible without prompting the uploader.  The issue is dealing with the input.  One is overriding the other and the php if that I tried to use failed.

If something is entered into the add new input field it should overwrite the dropdown values.

Comment: Hi Robert, I tried what you posted before reading your edit, I couldn't and still can't get this ******* to work :)

When New Category is selected the val "newCat" is always taken instead of the typed input